# Wireshark add signed 32 bit value as double in protocol tree

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

In my custom dissector, I have 32 bit signed *gint32* value in datagram, whose header field is described as

```
 &hf_TargetPosition,
{ "Target Position", "machine.RxPdo",
FT_INT32, BASE_DEC, NULL, 0xffffffff,
NULL, HFILL }
```

Before adding this item to proto_tree, I need to scale it with double value.
Since there is no tvb_get* function that return signed gint32, I used *tvb_get_letohl* function to get 32 bit signed value

```
gint32 stmp32 = (gint32)tvb_get_letohl(tvb, suboffset);
gdouble tpos = (gdouble)stmp32 * 0.000001;
```

How can I add tpos to proto_tree ?

As a workaround I tried not to cast *tpos* to double and use *proto_tree_add_int_format_value* function

```
gint32 tpos = stmp/1000000;
proto_tree_add_int_format_value(Dout_tree, hf_TargetPosition, tvb, suboffset, 4, tpos, "%lf");
```

But could not get desired signed decimal-point/float value in displayed tree.

Comment: "How can I add tpos to proto_tree ?"  Do you want to have the field's value be the raw integral value, i.e., a number of millionths of an meter or inch or..., and have it *display* as fractional meters or inches or..., or do you want to have the field's value be the scaled version, i.e. to be a floating-point value in units of meters or inches or...?

Comment: @GuyHarris I need it to be raw integral value and display it as fractional unit. As an example, for 'hf_TargetPosition' I get "stmp32 = 68977386", it should be added and displayed as 68.977386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need it to be raw integral value and display it as fractional unit.

Then you want

```
gint32 stmp32;

    ...

stmp32 = (gint32)tvb_get_letohl(tvb, suboffset);
proto_tree_add_int_format_value(Dout_tree, hf_TargetPosition, tvb, suboffset, 4, stmp32, "%lf", stmp32/1000000.0);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.